# C++ operator-comma / forward reference code doesn't compile

Tags: c++

The following code doesn't compile, unless the commented line is uncommented:

```
template <class T> struct R { static T& r(); };
struct M {
    static char m(M&);
    template <class T> static int m(const T&);
};
template <class T> struct A;
template <class T>
struct B {
    struct U { };
    struct V { M& operator,(U); };
    enum { v = sizeof(M::m((R<V>::r(), R<A<T>*>::r()))) };
};
template <class T> struct A { B<T> y; };
int main()
{
//  A<int>();  // Works if uncommented.
    B<int>();
}
```

At the comma operator, the compiler thinks that it needs `A<int>` to be complete, even though the code only traffics in `A<T>*`.  I don't understand why.  It fails with both clang and g++. Clang says

```
h.cpp:13:36: error: field has incomplete type 'B<int>'
template <class T> struct A { B<T> y; };
                                   ^
h.cpp:11:38: note: in instantiation of template class 'A<int>' requested here
    enum { v = sizeof(M::m((R<V>::r(), R<A<T>*>::r()))) };
                                     ^
h.cpp:17:5: note: in instantiation of template class 'B<int>' requested here
    B<int>();
    ^
h.cpp:8:8: note: definition of 'B<int>' is not complete until the closing '}'
struct B {
       ^
1 error generated.
```

---

I'm now sitting in the debugger debugging the compiler :-)  I think what's happening is that the compiler is using argument-dependent lookup to find matching `operator,`s and the associated classes and namespaces for a pointer to a class include the class itself, so the compiler wants the class to be complete.  Maybe.

Comment: so what's your question?

Comment: Why doesn't it compile?  Why does the compiler want `A<int>` to be complete when looking at `operator,(B::V, A<int>*)`?  Why does it work when the commented line is uncommented?

Comment: what did the error output from the compiler say?

Comment: You might want to mention which compiler just in case there is more than one out there.

Comment: shall we start at the other end? Are you able to locate a reference that suggests that the code *should* compile, according to the standard?

Comment: The description of the comma operator doesn't give me any reason to believe that having the rhs be a pointer requires that it be a pointer to a complete type.  And I don't see why `A<int>()` in `main()` then makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

you get the same error message if you change main to be this:

```
int main()
{
    // A<int>();  // Works if uncommented.

    auto& x = R<A<int>*>::r();
    B<int>();
}
```

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that it's as you hinted. Mentioning a pointer to an `A<int>` does not cause a template expansion of `A<int>`.

This makes sense (to me), since it's the same as mentioning a pointer to a forward-declared type - you don't need the type fully defined at that point.

Perhaps someone wiser than me can find the passage in the standard that mandates this.